# Add/remove image from navigation bar

Tags: menus, css, navigation

I am picking up the work from one of our developers who has left our company and applied a background on our header seen here http://3.20.227.107/. When you scroll down you will see the header has a orange circle in the cop right hand side. How do I get rid of this? I see in the code it has to do with uk-navbar-container but where can I edit this within wordpress? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there are many ways and many possibilities for adding a image to the bar.
It is really hard to tell how to remove it directly.

However, it looks like it is controlled in CSS and you could try the following.

You may try to look for a `theme1.css` file and then search for `.uk-navbar-container:not(.uk-navbar-transparent)`

You will see

```
/* ... skipped here */

    background-image: url(orange-circle2.svg);

/* ... skipped here */
```

change to

```
/* ... skipped here */

    background-image: none; /* <--- change to none to hide the image */

/* ... skipped here */
```

Comment: Omg....THANK YOU! That did it

Comment: And another question for you @simongcc, how do I change the color from the menu dropdowns from purple to something else? I tried going into theme editor but I change any value and the formatting on the site gets destroyed

Comment: You may search '.uk-navbar-dropdown-nav>li>a:hover' to change the color. It is called hover when you hover on the link. You may use Chrome or any browser with inspector tools to find out the actual css that affect the style. You may refer to [this video](https://designtlc.com/use-chrome-inspector-edit-website-css/) which I just find randomly for an example. It should help you in long run and identify the style class that you are looking for.

Comment: So most edits should be made through the theme1.css file?

Comment: For your site, I guess so, different websites, different setup and filenames. And the css is only controlling the skin (Frontend or Display) to user. For backend or php code, it is another story.